# CSS Animation of SVG fill (IE Issues)

Tags: css, internet-explorer, svg, css-animations

Been working on this one element off and on for days now, and got it working all the way down to one stupid little Internet Explorer bug. If only IE just supported SMIL!

Everything is working, except in IE where the css animation does not seem to take to the SVG fill attribute.

Essentially I have this as the CSS:

```
.fill {

animation: logo 15s ;
{

@keyframes logo {
0%   {fill: #000000;}
100%  {fill: #ffffff;}
}
```

And then in the SVG:

```
<path class="fill" d="Blahblah"/>
```

It works perfectly fine in -webkit-. It doesn't work at all in IE.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the `{` after `animation: logo 15s ;` is just a failed copy, you could try prefixing it:

```
.fill { 
    -ms-animation: logo 15s;
    animation: logo 15s;
}

@keyframes logo {
    0%    { fill: #000000; }
    100%  { fill: #ffffff; }
}
@-ms-keyframes logo {
    0%    { fill: #000000; }
    100%  { fill: #ffffff; }
}
```

In order to serve some older browsers, you should probably do the same for `-moz-` and `-webkit-` prefixes as well

Comment: It was a failed copy- for some reason or other IE just doesn't like to alter the "fill" attribute. Finally settles on simply using Modernizr.js to detect SMIL animation and creating a .png with a CSS-animated Div behind it (Used as a fallback if -webkit-/-moz-/-ms- fails).

Works perfectly for what I needed it for. Thanks for the help, though!

Comment: You'd have to provide more info/code for us to help finding the problem. It *should* be working based on the code provided